# Regression of a binary vector from another binary vector in Keras

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models, vector

I am trying to work on building a relationship in `Keras`, between X and Y where  `X= (1,30)` and `Y= (1,10)`.

I made `model`, to predict the Y from X. I am working in the biology field, and I want to predict the binary vector of `Y`  through `X` with accuracy (90%) .

I will explain mode: `X` is a binary vector of length n (e.g., `X(1,:) = [0/1, 0/1, ..., 0/1]).`
`Y` is a binary vector of length m, where `m < n` (e.g., `Y(1,:) = [0/1, 0/1, ..., 0/1]`).

For each X => Y
the data is like that  : for example a sample :

```
X = [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1] and its Y=[0,1,1,1,1,0,1]
```

My objective is to develop a machine learning model `M` that can predict the vector Y from the vector X with an accuracy greater than `90%`. I accept only an error of 1 bit ! not more.

My question, what is the best cost function and loss function should I use ?

Comment: This sounds like a fairly routine multi-label problem. Do you see it any different?

Comment: I think it is a regression

Comment: If you are sure that accuracy is what you want ([it often isn't](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)), then by all means, go ahead and use that. Let's hope that biology obliges your goals by being sufficiently predictable (it often isn't).

Comment: I want predect Y correctly that s what I am looking for 
So I don't know is it classification or regression ( I want make it regression )

Comment: Could you please say what you mean when you use the terms `classification` and `regression`? To me, this is kind a “would a rose by any other name” situation, but I’d like the communication to be as smooth as possible.